# Converting AngularJS resource to JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, mean-stack

I got a response for user details as Resource Object. I need to convert it to JSON. I tried

```
angular.toJson(res_obj)
```

but it gave empty string.
[image]

The first one is `console.log(res_obj)`. The second response is `console.log(angular.toJson(res_obj))`.

I am new to Angular. Please help me with this.

Comment: I think res_obj may be the string.Can you try angular.fromJson()?

Comment: Nope, `typeof(res_obj)` gave output as `Object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print your object, the resource is not resolved (as shown in the first line of your printscreen). You have to wait until the resource is resolved to print it to JSON

You can do something like that:

```
 res_obj.$promise.then(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
 });
```